# Proper Query for Archiving Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries written up, I am wondering which is best practice for archiving tables if my team chooses to go the route of using a query to do the archiving. We are looking for the solution that is most efficient but doesn't compromise any data integrity. We are looking to keep only the last 18 months in some of our biggest tables, no idea as of yet on how often we'll be running this archive, but I would imagine once a month.

**Option 1: Without a loop**

```
DECLARE @18Months datetime = DATEADD(m, -18, CAST(GETDATE() AS Date))

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION t1
    INSERT INTO tblOneArchive
        SELECT * FROM tblOne WHERE dateField < @18Months
    DELETE FROM tblOne WHERE datefield < @18Months
COMMIT TRANSACTION t1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
END CATCH
```

**Option 2: With a loop**

```
DECLARE @id INT
SELECT @id = MIN(ID) FROM tblOne WHERE dateField < @18Months
WHILE @id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION t2
    INSERT INTO tblOneArchive
        SELECT * FROM tblOne WHERE ID = @id
    DELETE FROM tblOne WHERE ID = @id
    COMMIT TRANSACTION t2
    SELECT @id = MIN(ID) FROM tblOne WHERE ID > @id AND dateField < @18Months
END
```

If Option 2 is best, how should I handle the try catch? Thanks.

Comment: You did not state your SQL Server's version... You might read about [partitioned tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: A loop processing a block of rows, e.g. 10000 per iteration, is a common means of managing the transaction log space. The transaction isolation level is important re: blocking other processes while capturing accurate data. Avoiding [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/) is a good thing. (See [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).)

Comment: This depends on soooo many factors. @Shnugo beat me to the punch, but I was going to ask, too, if you've looked at a sliding window partitioning scheme. It's a pain to set up, but once it's there, it's pretty carefree.

Comment: @Shnugo we are running v17.4 of SSMS but I believe the server itself is still on 2008, we plan on migrating to 2016 within the next few months.

Comment: Define "efficient".  Option 2 is terrible - deleting row by row. Others have given you links. Before you decide, you need to define your performance goals. Managing log usage is one. Avoiding blocking might be another. Duration of the process is another. Etc. You can't manage what you don't measure.

Comment: @SMor deleting on a clustered index wouldn't be efficient? I figured since you are using a clustered index as well as other conditions it wouldn't be an issue. Not to mention I was asking more about the choice between a loop or no loop, I can always choose to loop and grab say 1,000 at a time instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 with using fast order delete. Check it out here https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/04/how-to-delete-just-some-rows-from-a-really-big-table/